# Joining 2 Column with identical Id

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008

My problem is how can i join the selected rows with identical ID but different contacts

This is the output of what I'm doing

```
|     Name     |    Address   |     Cellphone    |     Email      | 
|     John     |     NY       |       n/a        |   johndoe@y.c  |
|     John     |     NY       |    123456781     |       n/a      |
```

And i want my output to be one liner combined

```
|     Name     |    Address   |     Cellphone    |     Email      | 
|     John     |     NY       |     123456781    |   johndoe@y.c  |
```

this is my Linq

```
var an = (from a in db.Info
          join b in db.Contact on a.ID equals b.InfoID
          where b.ContactTypeID == 56
             || b.ContactTypeID == 59
          select new
          {
              a.ID,
              a.LastName,
              a.FirstName,
              a.MiddleName,
              b.ContactTypeID,
              b.Values
          }).ToList();

List<InfoList> wlist = new List<InfoList>();

foreach (var row in an)
{
    InfoList ci = new InfoList
        {
            ID = row.ID,
            Name = row.FirstName + " " + row.MiddleName + " " + row.LastName,
            ContactType = GetLookupDisplayValById(row.ContactTypeID),
            ContactValue = row.Values
        };
    wlist.Add(ci);
}

return Json(wlist.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

For that data, and that data only, a self join would work.  Here is the sql that you could convert to linq.

```
select name, address
, case when t1.cellphone <> 'n/a' then t1.cellphone else t2.cellphone end cellphone
, case when t1.email <> 'n/a' then t1.email else t2.email end email
from yourtable t1 join your table t2 on t1.name = t2.name
where t1.name = 'John'
```

But, if the data looked like this,

```
|     Name     |    Address   |     Cellphone    |     Email      | 
|     John     |     NY       |    365418794     |   johndoe@y.c  |
|     John     |     NY       |    123456781     |       n/a      |
```

What sort of output would you want?

Comment: ive done that one on sql server query and my problem is how to translate it to linq

Answer (score -2):

```
select max(Name),MAX(Address),MAX(Cellphone),MAX(Email) from grp  group by Name
```